# Colour of points repeat after 10 data sets on D3.js scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Problem:**
I've got [a D3.js scatter plot](http://josephrocca.com/osfmaterialrecognition/) that has 16 different data sets, but it seems like D3 has only 10 different colours built-in before it repeats. You can see what I mean by clicking that link.

**Code:**

```
function updatePlot() {

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sepalLength = +d.sepalLength;
    d.sepalWidth = +d.sepalWidth;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.sepalWidth; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.sepalLength; })).nice();

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("HPF/LPF Intensity Ratio");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("HPF Intensity (relative units)")

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.sepalWidth); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sepalLength); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});
}
```

(The code is pretty much copy/paste from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118) with a little customisation in the areas of D3 that I understand)

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this part of the [API doc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category10)

Comment: Try replacing `category10` with `category20`.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the docs has the answer: [Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors). Thanks to user and Lars Kotthoff!

Simply replaced `category10` with `category20`.